# Items seem not to be added to the session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

So I have some php trying to add an item onto the end of an array stored in `$_SESSION['basket']` using the code `array_push($_SESSION['basket'],$_POST['item']);`. The first item will be added just fine, however once there is an item present nothing else seems to be added to the array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$_SESSION['basket'][] = $_POST['item'];
```

If your array uses numeric index, is more efficiently than use of array_push.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign your `$_SESSION` variable. Simply calling `array_push()` on a session variable will not change it.

Something to the effect of:

```
$basket = array_push($_SESSION['basket'], $_POST['item']);
$_SESSION['basket'] = $basket;
```

should do the trick.

This, of course, assumes that `$_SESSION['basket']` is nonempty and you have access to your session variables.